# Find divergence free field with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

I search a divergence free vector field which is smooth and compactly supported. Take any divergence free vector field on some compact set and extend it by 0 on the outside. The vector field has compact support. This means that the convolution has compact support. Let $F$ be the name of the vector field. Is the divergence of the convolution the same as the convolution of the divergence? I think this should solve the problem. If we know
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(F\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon}) \nabla \varphi dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \text{div}(F \ast\varphi_{\varepsilon}) \varphi dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (\text{div}(F)\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon}) \varphi dx=0
\end{align}
where $\varphi_{\varepsilon}$ is the standard mollifier. This means for any weakly divergence free vector field with compact support we can find a smooth vector field with compact support right?

Comment: In $R^3$ you could take any smooth vector field with the desired compact support and use its curl.

Comment: Please write the details of your argument very carefully.